# phase transformation of liquid under motion

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I was testing in my lab with water and found that it starts to solidify when it is stationery at 0 degree centigrade.but when I move the liquid with some velocity it dosent change its phase.my interpretation of this happening because when I move liquid it has kinetic energy which dosent allow it to crystallize.but at certain velocity and further lowered temperature it should start crystallising again.is there any graph which shows at what velocity and temperature it crystallize with atmospheric pressure?as in phase transition of water under temperature and pressure?

Comment: Difficult problem to say the least.  Take a look at http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/gen01/gen01174.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I worked at Unilever we investigated the freezing of water being pumped through pipes as part of the study into making ice cream (the pipes in question were part of the plant making ice cream).

We found exactly what you describe. It's well known that very pure stationary water can be supercooled to well below zero, but even for not especially pure water rushing through pipes it could be cooled well below zero without nucleating any ice crystals. The only downside was that as soon as the flow stopped the whole thing immediately froze solid! I don't remember what our record low temperature was, but it was startlingly low - I think, though I wouldn't swear to it, that it was around -20°C.

I'm afraid we never looked into why the water could be supercooled. Our guess was that the turbulence of the flow prevented the nuclei from growing large enough to cause macroscopic freezing. At any temperature above around -50°C there is a kinetic barrier to the formation of ice crystals because it costs a lot of energy to nucleate an ice crystal.

Ig you consider the process of making a sperical ice crystal of radius $r$ the free energy change is given by something like:

$$ \Delta G (r) = 4\pi r^2 \gamma_{sl} - \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \rho \Delta G_{sl} $$

The first, positive, term is the increase in energy due to the formation of the ice/water boundary with an interfacial tension $\gamma_{sl}$, and the second negative term is the energy released by converting a volume of water to ice. At small $r$ the first term dominates, and forming an ice crystal actually increases the energy instead of decreasing it. You need to grow the crystal to a certain size before the free energy becomes negative and freezing procedes spontaneously. If you can put in enough mechanical energy to break up the nuclei before they get big enough to grow then you can stop the water freezing.

Comment: This is pretty fantastic.